# Why my ring won't work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to create a circular ring in Minecraft by using the `/summon MinecartRideable` command, but I couldn't keep the minecarts to keep there rotation.  When I summoned a bunch of rotated minecarts they gathered in a cylinder inside the block[image: When I summoned a bunch of rotated minecarts they gathered in a cylinder inside the block]   --As the minecarts fell they did take on the part of the ring I had created.[image]  --For some reason even if I summoned them inside a block they still all fell into a cylinder shape, like in image #1.

This is the type of command I'm using.  Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

`/summon MinecartRideable 16.321 68 186.499 {CustomDisplayTile:1,DisplayTile:159,DisplayData:4,DisplayOffset:84,Rotation:[11f,130f]}`

I think this is the original video by Logdotzip I watched to figure this out:

Answer (score 1):

I think they point up after some time.Create a clock for summoning commands.I suggest killing the old minecarts though.